# Hive allowed column names

Tags: hive

I am completely new to Hive. While creating a Hive table, I came across following error:

```
 >create table coffee (WINDOW int);

 Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:23 
 cannot recognize input near 'WINDOW' 'int' ')' in column specification 
 (state=42000,code=40000)
```

When I digged more, I realized its happening due to reserve keyword "Window"  which I have used while creating table in Hive. Can I get a list of **all reserve keyword** in Hive which can not be used as a **column name**. I got a list of reserve keywords at following link, but I am able to use lot of listed reserve keywords as column name from it while creating table.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL

Comment: Actually, the list of "reserved words" depends on the Hive version, and the list of *actually* reserved words for column names also depends on the Hive version. Avoid every "reserved word" to stay on the safe side.

Answer (score 3):

you can use backtick  quotes to create tables/column with keyword names like this

```
create table coffee (`WINDOW` int);
```

Anyway, I would recommend choose a different name, if you want to select the data by column name, you will also must use the backtick quotes

Answer (score -1):

You can't use reserved keywords as column name.
WINDOW is a reversed keyword. So use some other name for your variable.

**Edit**: use backtick quotation (``) like below:

```
create table coffee ( `WINDOW` int);
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in my description. I know that WINDOW is reserve keyword which can not be used. My question is that if there any list of reserve keywords which can not be used as a Hive Column..

Comment: Use reserve keyword within backtick quotation  (``), it will allow you to use as column name.